# How to get the first ID from the repeated data with different ID's

Tags: php, arrays

In a table I have repeated data which I need to clean but not delete, it has to be "re-organized" so I have manage to clean most of the data, and in return I have a basic array as follow:

```
array (
    [0] => array (
    [id] => 1
    [email] => tu@al.com
    )
    [1] => array (
    [id] => 2
    [email] => tu@al.com
    )
    [2] => array (
    [id] => 3
    [email] => ta@aa.com
    )
    [3] => array (
    [id] => 4
    [email] => tu@al.com
    ) // ... and so on about 10K records...
)
```

So I have this code so I can do some deep cleaning...

```
$rep = array();
foreach ($f as $cl=>$vl) {
    if(!in_array($vl['email'], $rep)) {
        $rep[] = $vl['email'];
        // Unique Data just leave it as this data is in "clean" table
    } else {
        // Repeated Data, insert it in a different Table with association ID
        // Delete this record with ID X from Clean Table
    }
}
```

So here is the thing... in order for me to make a "nice" association I need to "move" the repeated data in this case ID's 2, and 4, so I use INSERT INTO... BUT I need the ID of the first record that has the repeated data latter on that way I can associate the information...

Table 1:

```
-------------- 
ID | email    |
1  |tu@al.com |
2  |tu@al.com |
3  |ta@aa.com | <-- Unique record
4  |tu@al.com |
---------------
// Code here to do the magic
```

Table Assoc:

```
------------------------ 
ID | id_tb1 | Email     |
1  |1       | tu@al.com |
2  |1       | tu@al.com |
------------------------
```

So when the foreach has finish, the final table should look like this, which is the "Table 1"

```
-------------- 
ID | email    |
1  |tu@al.com |
3  |ta@aa.com |
---------------
```

To make the table 1 toke me about 4hrs since this "dirty" tables had json on the columns so I had to clean all of that and associate the information in order to make "Table 1", now Table 1 has about 21 columns but the most important is the email...

Comment: *Scenario:* You've determined that the current record is a duplicate. You can get the array key of the record that it is a duplicate of by `array_search($email, $rep)`, then you can get the ID out of that and use it when you insert the duplicate record's data.

Answer (score 0):

So if you only care to get the first id of a list with no repeating emails, I suggests use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 GROUP BY email ORDER BY id;
```

And if you want to get that data in another tabla just need the insert you know:

```
INSERT INTO table_2([columns]) (SELECT * FROM table_1 GROUP BY email ORDER BY id);
```

Just remember both tables must get the same columns and order, or specify the columns in the Insert and in the Select (in order).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I saw, I had to build another array, and after the ELSE I had to put another foreach...

```
$rep = array();
$rep2 = array();
foreach ($f as $cl=>$vl) {
    if(!in_array($vl['email'], $rep)) {
        $rep[] = $vl['email'];
        $rep2[] = array('id'=>$vl['id'], 'emails'=>$vl['email']);
        // Unique Data just leave it as this data is in "clean" table
    } else {
        // Repeated Data, insert it in a different Table with association ID
        // Delete this record with ID X from Clean Table
        foreach (rep2 as $kr => $vr ) {
            if($vr['emails'] == $vl['email']) {
              // Here is where I get the ID of the first record that latter 
              // get repeated... 
              echo 'Repeated Record ID unique: ' . $vr['id]; // in this case is ID 1
              // Now we can insert the repeated data in the assoc Table with ID
              // Repetition, just like in table assoc... 
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Problem solved... :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want all data use this

```
$rep = array();
$first_id = array();
foreach ($f as $cl=>$vl) {
if(!in_array($vl['email'], $rep)) {
    $rep[] = $vl['email'];
    if(!in_array($vl['email'], $first_id))
        {
            $first_id[$vl['id']]=$vl['email'];

        }
    // Unique Data just leave it as this data is in "clean" table
} else {


    // Repeated Data, insert it in a different Table with association ID
    // Delete this record with ID X from Clean Table
}
}
```

if you want only repeated use this

```
$rep = array();
$first_id = array();
foreach ($f as $cl=>$vl) {
if(!in_array($vl['email'], $rep)) {
    $rep[] = $vl['email'];

    // Unique Data just leave it as this data is in "clean" table
} else {

    if(!in_array($vl['email'], $first_id))
        {
            $first_id[$vl['id']]=$vl['email'];

        }
    // Repeated Data, insert it in a different Table with association ID
    // Delete this record with ID X from Clean Table
}
}
```